# site 5x faster via mod_rewrite, but CSS images are broken

Tags: css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, image, subdomain

I am using .htaccess to accelerate a site with the following redirects:

```
request for http://example.com/images/name.jpg  routed to  http://i.example.com/name.jpg
request for http://example.com/css/name.css     routed to  http://c.example.com/name.css
```

From listening to the Stack Overflow podcast, I learned that this could make a site faster, since **the browser can download more files simultaneously** (apparently two streams per domain, although this is unconfirmed).

Indeed, the difference is dramatic; the page loads about **five times as fast**!

I have not touched the original folders and images -- I am just using mod_rewrite to change the addresses from **example.com/images/** to **i.example.com/**:

```
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST}     !^i\.example\.com       [NC]
rewriterule ^images/([^/]+)$ http://i.example.com/$1 [L]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST}     !^c\.example\.com       [NC]
rewriterule ^css/([^/]+)$    http://c.example.com/$1 [L]
```

The problem I have is that this technique works perfectly for image tags included in html, but doesn't work for images included via stylesheets:

> **img src=/images/logo.jpg** works perfectly
>
> **background:url(/images/logo.jpg);** does not work

The server error log contains the following entry:

> File does not exist: /var/www/html/css/images, referer: http://example.com/page.html

This seems to imply that the rewrite rule is being applied incorrectly.

The stylesheets work if I use:

> **background:url(http://i.example.com/logo.jpg);**

However, in order to avoid rewriting all the style sheets, I'd like to know: **why doesn't url rewriting apply to stylesheets the way it does to html img tags**.

**[update1]** This problem exists in Safari 4 Beta, Firefox 3.0.3, and Chrome, but the **page works perfectly in IE6**.

**[update2]** Adding [L,R=301] and [L,R=302] did not help.

**[update3]** I tried the following based on Gumbo's suggestion below:

Redirect externally if path doesn’t match host name:

```
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST}     !^i\.domain\.com$
rewriterule ^images/([^/]+)$ http://i.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST}     !^c\.domain\.com$
rewriterule ^css/([^/]+)$    http://c.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Redirect internally; if there's an unnecessary folder name remove it (see server error above):

```
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST}     ^i\.domain\.com$
rewriterule ^images/([^/]+)$ $1 [L]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST}     ^c\.domain\.com$
rewriterule ^css/([^/]+)$    $1 [L]
```

It still didn't work. Bizarrely, the server error is:

> File does not exist: /var/www/html/css/var, referer: http://domain.com/page.html

Comment: Are you really using absolute paths in the stylesheet?

Comment: Well the only explanation for this behavior I have is that the relative path “images/foo” in the stylesheet “/css/bar” is (correctly) resolved to “/css/images/foo”. Using absolute paths instead would solve this problem.

Comment: I went back and verified, and they really are absolute paths. Since the behavior changes in different browsers, it may have something to do with the way browsers try to interpret CSS images for caching reasons. I also tried ../images and ../../images, still broken.

Comment: Besides this problem: Your method will result in a 302 external redirect and thus double the number of requests. Are you sure you want this? Why don’t you use the different domains in the first place?

Comment: maybe the stylesheet thinks it is located at c.example.com and looks for the urls at c.example.com/images/logo.jpg ?

Comment: Even though there are double the number of requests, the result is really fast -- the first request takes almost no time; it's downloading the files that goes much faster. The reason to do it this way is that it's extremely simple and non-invasive to set up and manage.

Comment: Are example.com, c.example.com and i.example.com on the same webserver so that these rules also apply to the latter ones? And have you tried a 301 redirect instead an implicit 302 redirect?

Comment: This bizarr error message could arise from when MultiViews is enabled.

Comment: With options -multiviews, I get: file does not exist: /var/www/html/css/images for the solution in my own answer, and: file does not exist: /var/www/htmlcss/var for the solution in update3 in the question -- nothing changed (this is with subdomains pointed directly to the directories).

Comment: I also added rewritebase / at the beginning of the .htaccess, and nothing changed.

Comment: I will test what happens on physically separate servers, to see if the browser is doing some kind of shortcut because the two domains have the same IP address.

Comment: @AndrewSwift: have you found any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by **not trying to incorporate directories into the subdomains**:

```
request for domain.com/images/  routed to  i.domain.com/images/
request for domain.com/css/     routed to  c.domain.com/css/
```

It works perfectly and is **still extremely fast**.

There seems to be a **bug** in modern browsers where a css request that is redirected will **apply only the new domain**, leaving the original directories as part of the request:

If a css image at **url(domain.com/images/name.jpg)** is redirected to **i.domain.com/name.jpg**, the browser will mistakenly request **i.domain.com/images/name.jpg**.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve this problem if all host names use the same virtual host:

```
# redirect externally if path doesn’t match host name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^i\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)$ http://i.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^c\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^css/([^/]+)$ http://c.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# redirect internally to the file
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^i\.example\.com$
RewriteRule !^images/ images%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^c\.example\.com$
RewriteRule !^css/ css%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This will do the following:

```
http://example.com/css/foo       externally to    http://c.example.com/foo
http://c.example.com/foo         internally to    /css/foo

http://example.com/images/bar    externally to    http://i.example.com/bar
http://i.example.com/bar         internally to    /images/bar
```

As well as correcting mismatching paths and host names:

```
http://i.example.com/css/foo     externally to    http://c.example.com/foo
http://c.example.com/images/bar  externally to    http://i.example.com/bar
```

A mismatch occurs when the requested stylesheet `http://example.com/css/foo` is redirected to `http://c.example.com/foo` and an image URI reference like `/images/bar` inside the stylesheet is resolved from this new base URI and thus leading to `http://c.example.com/images/bar` instead of the initial `http://example.com/images/bar`.

Comment: This solution remaps http://i.example.com/bar internally to    /images/bar, not what I need. What I thought would fix the initial problem was to remap http://i.example.com/images/bar to http://i.example.com/bar. It didn't work (see revised question).