# Serving static content from cookie free domain

Tags: html, css, wordpress, yslow

I am workin gon the recommendation of Yslow and Google page speed to serve static content from cookie free domain.

I have created two sub-domain to serve images and JS and CSS files

```
static.images.mymaindomainname.com
static.mymaindomainname.com
```

i have even configured them to point to same domain(alias) and they seems to working fine.I am in a confusion about using these sub-domain to serve static content.

In my CSS file i am using images as `images/my_image.jpg` and which resolve to `www.mymaindomainname.com/images/my_image.jpg` and now i have to point this to sub-domain, do i need to change each and every image path with the sub-domain URL like

```
images/my_image.jpg-->static.images.mymaindomainname.com/images/my_image.jpg
```

same is the case with JS file and we have many CSS file.
Do i need to change path of each and every individual entry? Please suggest

i am using wordpress for portal development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically rewrite urls without touching your current css or js files using .htaccess and mod_rewrite. Check out this post:

[site 5x faster via mod_rewrite, but CSS images are broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634089/site-5x-faster-via-mod-rewrite-but-css-images-are-broken)

Comment: or just do it in httpd.conf if you have access. ;)